# Как поменять цвет элемента в React по условию?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

У меня есть элемент  `<p>{percent_change_24h}</p>`, и нужно построить условие, если переменная `percent_change_24h` больше 0, то цвет - зелёный, а если меньше 0 - то красный. Как это можно реализовать через условный рендеринг или функцию? Не разобрался.

Подскажите, пожалуйста! Буду благодарен!

Answer (score 0):

> если переменная percent_change_24h больше 0, то цвет - зелёный, а если меньше 0 - то красный

Такое реализовать можно вот таким образом...

```js
//
function App() {
  const percent_change_24h = -10
  const s = {}
  if (percent_change_24h > 0) s.color = 'green'
  if (percent_change_24h < 0) s.color = 'red'
  return <p style={s}>{percent_change_24h}</p>
}

const domContainer = document.querySelector('#like_button_container');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(domContainer);
root.render(<App />);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<div id="like_button_container"></div>
```

Comment: Cпасибо большое!